# ¿Cómo cerrar un mat-dialog automáticamente después de mostrar un mensaje de éxito?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Tengo el siguiente formulario, al hacer click en el botón **agregar**, se despliega un mat-dialog donde se puede agregar una nueva descripción para después ser mostrada en la tabla, hace bien la operación y manda un mensaje de éxito, pero al cerrar ese mensaje de éxito se queda la ventana del mat-dialog y quiero que en automático se cierre cuando sale la ventana de exito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el Component.ts mando a llamar al metodo **openDialog** para que abra la ventana de agregar una nueva descripción que esta en el componente AgregarNuevo

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CatalogosServiceService } from './catalogos-service.service';
import { CatalogoProducto } from './CatalogoProducto';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { CatalogoSubProducto } from './CatalogoSubProducto';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { AgregarNuevoComponent } from './agregar-nuevo/agregar-nuevo.component';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'pruebaforms';
  panelOpenState = false;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['idProducto', 'descripcionProducto','botonTipoActions'];
  displayedColumnsSubProd: string[] = ['idSubProducto', 'descripcionSubProducto'];
  catProducto: CatalogoProducto[] = [];
  catSubProducto: CatalogoSubProducto[] = [];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  producto: CatalogoProducto = new CatalogoProducto();

  
  constructor(private catService: CatalogosServiceService, public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerCatalogoProducto();
    this.obtenerCatalogoSubProducto();
  }

  //obtiene la lista del cat producto
  dataSource: any;
   obtenerCatalogoProducto() {
    this.catService.obtenerCatProd().subscribe((response) => {
      this.catProducto = response.data;
      console.log('PRUEBA  CAT PROD  ', response.data);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.catProducto);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la lista del cat subproducto
  dataSourceSubProducto: any;
  private obtenerCatalogoSubProducto() {
    this.catService.obtenerCatSubProd().subscribe((response) => {
      this.catSubProducto = response.data;
      console.log('PRUEBA CAT SUBPROD  ', response.data);
      this.dataSourceSubProducto = new MatTableDataSource(this.catSubProducto);
      this.dataSourceSubProducto.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }


  openDialog():void{
    this.dialog.open(AgregarNuevoComponent,{
        width: '500px',
        height: '240px'
    });
  }

  async eliminar(element: any, row:any){
    console.log("ID    ", row.idProducto);
    const deleteAlert = Swal.fire({
      title: '¿Está seguro de eliminar los valores?',
      showDenyButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Si',
    });
    if((await deleteAlert).isConfirmed){

         const index = this.dataSource.data.indexOf(element);
          this.dataSource.data.splice(index);
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataSource.data);
         

      this.producto.idProducto = row.idProducto;
      console.log("IDDD  ", this.producto.idProducto);
      this.catService.eliminarProductos(this.producto).subscribe(data => {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'Éxito',
          text: 'Registro borrado correctamente'
        });
      })
    }
  }
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          PRODUCTO
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <form>
        <br>
        
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog()"> Agregar
          <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
          <ng-container matColumnDef="idProducto">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idProducto }}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="descripcionProducto">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>PRODUCTO</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput [value]="element.descripcionProducto" />
              </mat-form-field>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="botonTipoActions">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ACCIONES </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <button mat-icon-button color="primary">
                <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
              </button>
             
              <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="eliminar($event.target,element)">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
              </button>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
        </table>
      </form>
      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
      </mat-paginator>
    </mat-expansion-panel>

    <!----------   TABLA SUBPRODUCTO   -->
    <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          SUB PROD
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceSubProducto" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="idSubProducto">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID.</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.idSubProducto }}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="descripcionSubProducto">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>SUBPRODUCTO</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput [value]="element.descripcionSubProducto" />
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </ng-container>


        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsSubProd"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsSubProd"></tr>
      </table>
      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Select page of periodic elements">
      </mat-paginator>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

AgregarNuevoCompoennt.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { CatalogoProducto } from '../CatalogoProducto';
import { CatalogosServiceService } from '../catalogos-service.service';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-agregar-nuevo',
  templateUrl: './agregar-nuevo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agregar-nuevo.component.css']
})
export class AgregarNuevoComponent implements OnInit {
catalogoProductoModel: CatalogoProducto = new CatalogoProducto();
nuevoForm!: FormGroup;
descripcion = new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)]);

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AgregarNuevoComponent>, private catService: CatalogosServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nuevoForm = new FormGroup({
      descripcion: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)])
    })
  }

  agregar(){
    if(this.nuevoForm.valid){
      console.log("es valido")
      console.log("DESCRIPCION    ", this.nuevoForm.get('descripcion')?.value);
      this.catalogoProductoModel.descripcionProducto = this.nuevoForm.get('descripcion')?.value;
      this.catService.agregarNuevoProducto(this.catalogoProductoModel).subscribe(response => {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'Éxito',
          text: 'Agregado correctamente'
        });
      })
    }
  }


 restablecer(){
  this.nuevoForm.get('descripcion')?.reset();
 }


}
```

AgregarNuevo html

```
<form [formGroup]="nuevoForm">
    <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                    <mat-label>Descripcion:</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="descripcion">
                </mat-form-field>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <button mat-button (click)="agregar()">Agregar</button>
        <button mat-button (click)="restablecer()">Restablecer</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al cerrar la ventana de exito, desaparezca la ventana del mat-dialog?
que necesito agregar?

Answer (score 1):

Guardate el popup en una variable y podrías utilizar el `dialog.close()`

```js
  dialogAgregarNuevo:MatDialogRef<unknown, any>|undefined;
  openDialog():void{
    dialogAgregarNuevo =this.dialog.open(AgregarNuevoComponent,{
        width: '500px',
        height: '240px'
    });
  }
```

Y para cerrarlo

```js
  if(dialogAgregarNuevo!=null){dialogAgregarNuevo.close();}
```